# Trouble with setting up crontab in macOS terminal

Tags: cron

I am currently trying to schedule a cronjob to run a script every minute.

I researched on how to do this, and most of them said to open a new terminal window and type `crontab-l`. However, when I do this it doesn't do anything and it just goes to a new line, when its supposed to say something like "no crontab for root". Then I typed in crontab-e, but this gives me: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBMnK.png)

I am not sure what to do now, as I cannot proceed with the instructions found on the internet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to be clear to others reading this (I tried to edit the OP's post but I need to make six char change), the commands are `crontab -l` and `crontab -e` to list and edit respectively (note the space between the command and the flag following it, where the commands in UNIX use minus as a flag delimiter).

Had you run crontab -l you would have got nothing by default as you have no crontab set.

Run crontab -e will put you in a screen editor session, with crontab running whatever executable is configured in your $EDITOR variable which is vi by default.  This is in your image clip.

I recommend learning vi.  It's the default editor on most, if not every, UNIX/Linux install and worth learning. [Here's](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim/) a reasonable starting point for that.

To run the script every minute round the clock without any breaks, enter the following keystrokes into the crontab sessions:

```
i* * * * * /path/to/my/script<ESC>:x
```

which will enter insert mode with the leading 'i', enter

```
* * * * * /path/to/my/script
```

into the body of the file, then `<ESC>` to go into command mode, and `:x` to exit with saving.

`crontab -l` will now show you the entry.  If the script errors in some way, you will get UNIX mail in your system mail file.  Use mailx to read the mail.

Comment: I had figured this out a while back, but thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Great work. If I got the answer correct could I have the upvote please?

Comment: i would, but it doesn't look like i have enough reputation to do so :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant select it as the correct answer.